# /usr/bin/time of a C program with I/O does not yield results

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c, time

### UPDATE

I had very long lines in the file, and I put a newline after each 80th character (I used the `sed` command for that). Now the programs work fine. I can time them, and the results make sense.

*Though, I have no idea why that caused a problem.*

### TLDR;

Using the /usr/bin/time command on my C programs does not work as expected. The time command ends before the C program, sometimes without output. E.g.

```
/usr/bin/time ./cat_8 lorem_ipsum.txt
```

### Problem description

I am doing the exercise 8.1 of K&R of chapter 8.

> **Exercise 8-1**. Rewrite the program cat from Chapter 7 using read,
>   write, open and close instead of their standard library equivalents.
>   Perform experiments to determine the relative speeds of the two
>   versions.
>
> Excerpt From: Brian W. Kernighan. The C Programming Language, Second
>   Edition

You can see the programs below. The problem I have is with both programs.

I try to time the programs to compare them. The file size *lorem_ipsum.txt* is 35M.

```
me@virtualbox:~$ ls -hs lorem_ipsum.txt
35M lorem_ipsum.txt
```

The cat programs run without issue, but I cannot get a result from the `time` command for some reason. Google cannot help and I am clueless.

I compiled the programs with `gcc`, no options except the `-o` of course. I work on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Does anyone know what the problem might be or what I am doing wrong?

### Chapter 8 (cat_8 program)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void error(char *fmt, ...);

/* cat: concatenate file */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int fd;
    void filecopy(int, int);
    char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */

    if (argc == 1)
        filecopy(0, 1);
    else
        while (--argc > 0)
            if ((fd = open(*++argv, O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1)
                error("%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv);
            else {
                filecopy(fd, 1);
                close(fd);
            }

    return 0;
}

/* filecopy: copy file ifp to file ofp */
void filecopy(int fdin, int fdout) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;

    while ((n = read(fdin, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
        write(fdout, buf, n);

}
```

### Chapter 7 (cat_7 program)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* cat: concatenate file, version 2 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *fp;
    void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *);
    char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */

    if (argc == 1)
        filecopy(stdin, stdout);
    else
        while (--argc > 0)
            if ((fp = fopen(*++argv, "r")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv);
                exit(1);
            } else {
                filecopy(fp, stdout);
                fclose(fp);
            }

    if (ferror(stdout)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error writing stdout\n", prog);
        exit(2);
    }

    return 0;
}

/* filecopy: copy file ifp to file ofp */
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp) {
    int c;

    while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
        putc(c, ofp);

}
```

Comment: sometimes? What does `strace` show `time` sometimes doing? E.g. `strace -f -o trace time ...`

Comment: `strace` has the same issue. *sometimes* means that I can see the output somewhere in the middle of the text that is displayed on the screen. It's just so much text that I cannot scroll all the way up to the command in the shell. It could be that the output is somewhere before the visible shell; in other words the `time` command and the C program might be running concurrently. Not sure though.

Comment: cat_7 is calling `close` on a `FILE*` which is wrong; your compiler should have complained unless it is using the 27-year-old C standard (and IMO even then it should _warn_). This is likely to lose some of the output, but on no reasonable system should it lose 35M.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for the bug. I corrected it. When I have time I'll try sourcejedi's suggestion on the machine linked. It must be my file because everybody says program looks *ok*. But I don't see what is wrong. I can open my file with `vim` and `gedit`; it looks ok to me. I don't know where to search....

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know what the problem might be or what I am doing wrong?

I don't believe it's anything wrong in your two solutions.  There's simply no way these could request the behaviour you describe... without deliberately forking a second process (and you don't call `fork()`), or killing the `time` process, or hacking the kernel etc.

Perhaps your computer is broken.

Previously I've had weird behaviour caused by silent disk corruption.  I might try running `debsums` or `rpm --verify -a` to check.

It could equally be a bug in the chain of software which displays the output.

For example [gnome-terminal 3.22 has a crash bug when fed some sequence of binary](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394154).  Several versions of the Linux kernel had [this great bug where sending more than 4kB over a terminal emulator ("pseudo-tty") to a read-line enabled program such as a shell, could lose some lines](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1208740).  Dumping 35MB of text at a time is *relatively* unusual, there could be some bug like that in your OS.

If you can reproduce the problem with an input file of a mere 100kB, [here's a different computer for you](https://bellard.org/jslinux/) which is almost certainly not *corrupted* in the same way as the host computer it is run on.  Console output is pretty slow, there's only a few megabytes of free space as well.  The output from running your program under `time` will not match real seconds for some reason, it shouldn't matter for this question though.  The clipboard text box doesn't accept keyboard input for me (Firefox 53), so I used the right-click menu to copy data in through `/dev/clipboard` as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the program work.

Does your time command work right?

Try:

```
leisner@y50 ~ $ /usr/bin/time sleep 10s                                                                                                                 
0.00user 0.00system 0:10.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1728maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+75minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Also are you mixing the output into the time result -- try something like:

```
time cat myfile.txt >/dev/null
```

It shouldn't -- but running in a VM causes an extra layer of buffering.